# Cookieless ASP.Net sessions for static pages

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, cookieless

I'm using [ASP.Net cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) so that the session ID for the application is tracked by placing it in the URL via a 302 redirect, for example if the user were to access the below URL

```
http://yourserver/folder/default.aspx
```

They would then be redirect to a URL similar to the following which would then proceed to serve up the actual page content

```
http://yourserver/folder/(S(849799d1-7ec0-41dc-962d-a77e1b958b99))/default.aspx
```

The problem I have is that **the entry point for the application is actually a static page** (e.g. one with a .html extension), **and ASP.Net is not issuing a session ID & redirecting the user for this page.**  This therefore means that links to ASP.Net hosted content (e.g. links, iframes etc...) each result in a new session ID being created for each of these links.  I cannot easily change the pages extension for compatability reasons (although this does fix the problem).

How can I prompt ASP.Net to create a session for my page?  I've tried adding an explicit handler mapping to ensure that the page is being handled by the ASP.Net modules, however this has no impact - while debugging I can see that a `SessionIDManager` instance is being created for this page (implying that the ASP.Net is already handling this page via the integrated pipeline regardless of my handler mapping), however ASP.Net is still not creating a session for this page.

I am using IIS 7, however this also needs to work on IIS 6 (with expicit handler mappings) and IIS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered from experimentation and decompiling the ASP.Net source that the `SessionStateModule` decides whether or not to create a session for a request based on whether or not the `IHttpHandler` for the request implements `IRequiresSessionState` or `IReadOnlySessionState`.  If neither of those are true then its all down to whether or not someone has used [`SetSessionStateBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.setsessionstatebehavior.aspx) to set the session state behaviour to either `Required` or `ReadOnly`.

By default the static file handler does not do any of these and so the session is not created for static files - to ensure that the session state behaviour is set for the static files that require session state I simply set the session state behaviour during the `BeginRequest` event for the application

```
// In Global.asax.cs
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Default);
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways, but this worked for me.